# Can't set indentation to 4 spaces because hook is not called

Tags: init-file, indentation, hooks

I'm trying to set the indentation in C++ files to be 4 spaces. To achieve this I have the following config:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)

(defun init-c-cpp ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (setq indent-line-function 'c-indent-line)
  )

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'lsp 'init-c-cpp '(lambda () (print "hello")))
```

I know there are already questions concerning this topic, but none of the answers worked for me.

The problem is that after opening a `.cpp` file in C++ mode, indentation is still at 2 spaces. In fact, `C-h v c-basic-offset` inside a C++ mode buffer shows that it is set to `2`. Also `"hello"` is not printed to the minibuffer upon opening the C++ file, which I expected to happen. It seems like the hook is not being called at all. Why could this be? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add-hook` takes only a single hook function to add, plus two other optional arguments.

Do this instead:

```lisp
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'init-c-cpp)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook (lambda () (print "hello"))
```

(Note also that lambdas are not quoted.)

You can read the documentation for `add-hook`, which will tell you what arguments it takes, by typing `C-h f` and then typing the function name. If point is already on something that looks like a function name, it will be the default and you can just hit enter at the prompt.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Also, why does the accepted answer in this question assert that chaining multiple hook functions is valid? https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45322/adding-multiple-functions-to-a-hook

Comment: You misread that answer. matteol recommended creating a single function which calls the others, and then adding that one function to the hook list.

Comment: "You can add multiple functions to the same hook" in the linked answer meant "you can call `add-hook` multiple times for the same hook, adding a different function each time."  In *this* answer, `c++-mode-hook` is the hook, to which multiple functions are being added.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the ambiguity